# How to sort an array of objects by a string property

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Take this for example:

```
var data = [
{ name: 'Random 100 Index' },
{ name: 'Random 25 Index' },
{ name: 'Random 75 Index' },
{ name: 'Random 50 Index' } ];
```

I want to sort this array based on the **name** property in ascending order. I've tried various techniques with jQuery & Underscore.js and I didn't get what I was looking for. The problem is that the *Random 100 Index* will be the first item in the sorted array.
Take this function for example:

```
function sortByProperty(property) {
'use strict';
return function (a, b) {
    var sortStatus = 0;
    if (a[property] < b[property]) {
        sortStatus = -1;
    } else if (a[property] > b[property]) {
        sortStatus = 1;
    } 
    return sortStatus;
}; }
```

When I do `var result = data.sort(sortByProperty('name'));` the result is the following:

```
[{ name: 'Random 100 Index' }, { name: 'Random 25 Index }, { name: 'Random 50 Index' }, { name: 'Random 75 Index' } ]
```

The items have been sorted correctly, except the **Random 100 Index** should be the last item.

How can I resolve this? How do you sort an array of strings like this?

Comment: you mean the number should be the criterium for sorting?

Comment: well the results are right, 100 comes before 25 alphabetically.

Comment: What "underscore.js" tag does here?

Comment: Does "Alpha 100 Index" come before or after "Bravo 25 Index" ? (i.e Is it *just* the number which controls the sorting or the text as well?)

Comment: If you have a solution in underscore please share, that's why the tag is here.

Comment: The thing is, I have a big JSON object with a number of child collections, and I have to sort the array based on a string property `display_name`. I could write a custom iterator for this case, but I wanted a generic solution to sort on strings properly.

Comment: BTW. Why the heck did I receive two down votes for this question?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** and **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**. Find integer value from string using **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**, based on that sort the array with help of **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**.

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Random 100 Index'
}, {
  name: 'Random 25 Index'
}, {
  name: 'Random 75 Index'
}, {
  name: 'Random 50 Index'
}];


var res = data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.name.match(/\d+/)[0] - b.name.match(/\d+/)[0];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res,null,2) + '</pre>');
```

**UPDATE :** It will only sort based on the first occurrence of digits in the string.

Comment: you can also just write `data = data.sort`. Also, you might want to `parseInt` the match result

Comment: This code will only work for the strict template `'Random N Index'`.

Answer (score 1):

Result with temp storage of index and value for large data sets.

```js
var data = [
        { name: 'Random 100 Index' },
        { name: 'Random 25 Index' },
        { name: 'Random 75 Index' },
        { name: 'Random 50 Index' }
    ],
    result = data.map(function (el, i) {
        return {
            index: i,
            value: /\d+/.exec(el.name)[0]
        };
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value;
    }).map(function (el) {
        return data[el.index];
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina this works. I'm testing your solution and **Pranav**'s against a few data sets, I'll update the entry with my results.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to **Pranav C Balan** and **Nina Scholz** I've come up with the following solution.

To sort an array alphabetically:

```js
function sortByProperty(property) {
    'use strict';
    return function (a, b) {
        var sortStatus = 0;
        if (a[property] < b[property]) {
            sortStatus = -1;
        } else if (a[property] > b[property]) {
            sortStatus = 1;
        }
 
        return sortStatus;
    };
}

var result = data.sort(sortByProperty('name'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And to sort the array based on the 1st digit found within a property's text:

```js
var res2 = res1.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name.match(/\d+/)[0] - b.name.match(/\d+/)[0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Pretty straightforward.
Thank you all :)

Comment: For string sort, i suggest to use `String.prototype.localeCompare`, eg `function sortByProperty(property) {
   return function (a, b) {
    return a[property].localeCompare(b[property]);
   }
  }`.